# How can I remove "" from a string in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings that were read from a .txt file, and each string was framed by quotes"". Is there a reason .rstrip does not work to remove quotes? Is there a better method for removing the quotes? Example code below:

```
NewList = ['"first"','"second"','"third"']
for x in NewList:
    x.strip('"')
    print(x)
```

Output:

"first"
"second"
"third"

Comment: `strip` returns a new string since strings are immutable

Comment: @Sayse - Thanks, this was my first post and your comment helped me solve my problem. y = x.strip('"") print(y) - success!